# Javascript: Recursive function with promise and resolve when count is reached

Tags: javascript, promise

I am stuck trying to build a recursive function that is already defined as a promise.

I have not been able to apply the recursive pattern on the code below which is **looping only once** even though `loopFor` is initialised at `20` what I am missing?

Requirement: `receivingMessages` must be a promise.

```js
let globalMessageArray = [];
let count = 0;
let loopFor = 20;

function receivingMessages(params, loopFor, globalMessageArray) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const command = new ReceiveMessageCommand(params);
        client.send(command).then(
            (data) => {
                if (data && data.Messages && data.Messages.length) {
                    data.Messages.forEach(msg => {
                        globalMessageArray.push(msg);
                    });
                };
                return resolve(globalMessageArray);
            },
            (error) => {
                return reject(error);
            }).then(
            (globalMessageArray) => {
                count = count + 1;
                console.log("Loop Count: " + count); // always returns 1
                if (loopFor === 1) {
                    return resolve(globalMessageArray);
                } else {
                    return resolve(receivingMessages(params, loopFor - 1, globalMessageArray));
                };
            });

    });
};
```

Comment: Instead of the `.then`s, use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Thanks @code ! Unfortunately the code is already wrapped within an `async/await`, I can't use this pattern here. What's wrong with `then`s in this context ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Just because a function is "wrapped with async/await", whatever that means, doesn't mean the function itself may not use it.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't been clear enough @code .
`receivingMessages` is already chained with 5 others promises in another part of the code. Using `async/await`would imply to rewrite the whole program which I would rather avoid.

Or perhaps what I am trying to achieve is impossible with `then`s?

Comment: Actually, you may need to clarify on what is not working. Can you clarify on what issue you're facing? Besides that, do note that the expression `if (loopFor = 1)` will always succeed, and the only thing it does is assign `loopFor` to `1`. You may  have meant `if (loopFor === 1)`. That's why your recursive call never ever happens.

Comment: It is really an ashaming mistake I made @code, thanks for that - probably due to already hours on this. Despite the fix, the code is only looping once.
I have edited for more clarity.

Comment: In the first then callback `client.send(cmd).then(data => …` you `return resolve(globalMessageArray)`. This effectively short-circuit your loop. You should just `return globalMessageArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first then callback `client.send(cmd).then(data => …` you `return resolve(globalMessageArray)`. This effectively short-circuit your loop, because a promise can only `resolve` once. Later call of `resolve` has no effect.

```js
client.send(cmd).then((data) => {
    …
    return globalMessageArray;
}, …
```

Remove first call to `resolve` should solve your problem.

---

You said in comment:

> Using async/await would imply to rewrite the whole program

No, your understanding of async/await is wrong. Any async function is automatically a promise returning function, which meets your requirement. Async/await is just syntax sugar on top of promise.

This means you can safely rewrite ONLY `receivingMessages` function without needing to modify other places that call it.

Although there is nothing wrong with vanilla promise, rewriting to async/await will make your code so much cleaner.

```js
async function receivingMessages(params, loopFor, globalMessageArray) {
    const command = new ReceiveMessageCommand(params);
    const data = await client.send(command);
    
    if (data && data.Messages && data.Messages.length) {
        data.Messages.forEach(msg => {
            globalMessageArray.push(msg);
        });
    }
             
    if (loopFor === 1) {
        return globalMessageArray;
    } else {
        return receivingMessages(params, loopFor - 1, globalMessageArray)
    };
};
```

Comment: You can replace `forEach` with `globalMessageArray.push(...data.Messages)`